# Count pattern in simpletest (PHP test framework)

Tags: php, testing, simpletest

How can I test if there is a string only once in a site? I use the WebTestCase from simpletest.

Comment: do you know what the string is?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database of all page names and you know the string you are looking for you could walk through the database and read each page, then searching each page for the string.

Comment: no database it's a kind of form processing and I need to check if the string is not more then one times send.